# In Hashtable methods are synchronized, not the table variable. Does that mean put and putIfAbsent(or remove) can run in parallel?

Tags: java, thread-safety, hashtable

In Java, **Hashtable** has individual methods synchronized and not the table instance variable. That means a put and a putIfAbsent(or remove) can still run in parallel, right ?

This means one should use other synchronization options for absolute thread safety or write safety using **Collections.synchronizedMap**(object-mutex level synchronization) or **ConcurrentHashMap**(segment level synchronization) !

If so we should not simply say that **Hashtable** is threadsafe. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what it means to declare a method 'synchronized'.  Such methods are synchronized on the object instance, so that only one can execute at a time on that particular object instance.

Comment: Oh Ok. That is my misunderstanding. It now makes sense to me.  Something to unlearn and relearn. :)

Comment: So basically, Java Thread acquires an object level lock when it enters into an instance synchronized java method and acquires a class level lock when it enters into static synchronized java method. [From reference]

Comment: Yes, that's it.